# Create a function in SqlServer which does not return anything

Tags: sql-server, function

I am creating a simple function which inserts a row to a table.
After the insertion I don't need the function to return anything.
I just checked the function creation syntax in MSDN and it seems like 
a function must return a value. I also tried to create a function but got syntax error.

I wonder if there is a way to create a function which doesn't return any value.

Can anyone please let me know if there is a way to create such a function?
Thanks in advance:)

Comment: Functions is meant to return some sort of value. If you just want a 'function' to execute an expression without any return value, then maybe what you want is a Stored Procedure.

Answer (score 18):

Then use Stored Procedure to achieve your requirement. Because function is meant for returning values.

Comment: Thanks, but can I call this new stored procedure inside other stored procedures?

Comment: Ok. I will create a proc then instead of function.

Comment: I have flagged this answer as 'This is not an answer'. It should had been a comment instead.

Answer (score 12):

create stored procedure instead of function

```
Create proc my_proc()
as
BEGIN
<your insert statement >

END
```

See [Examples here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/126898/Sql-Server-How-to-write-a-Stored-procedure-in-Sql)

Comment: Thanks, but can I call this new stored procedure inside other stored procedures?

Comment: Ok. I will create a proc then instead of function.

Answer (score 5):

In addition to the other answers, I'll add an obvious one:

> I am creating a simple function which inserts a row to a table.

A function can't insert a row into a table (by definition, a function in SQL Server is not supposed to have any side effects, which is different from functions in other languages), so whether or not you cared about returning a value, it can't be done anyway. You will need to use a stored procedure instead.

Answer (score 1):

According to SQL Server, you cant have a function without a return value. It has to return a value. In your case i would advise is to go for Stored procedure.

Comment: Do you have any source?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/return-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017